# How to use require.js inside js.erb file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2.16 and require.js ('requirejs-rails' gem).

My app has a module named `ExpensesUI` (here is a snippet of it):

```
$(function() {
  define('ExpensesUI', ['OperationsUI'], function(operationsUI) {
    var expenses = {
        operationConsolidatedCheckbox: "#operation_consolidated",
        parcelledNoCheckbox: "#operation_parcelled_no",
        parcelledYesCheckbox: "#operation_parcelled_yes",

        /* more things */
    };
  }
});
```

I can use it perfectly in any .js file with:

```
require(['ExpensesUI'], function(expensesUI) { console.log(expensesUI.parcelledNoCheckbox); });
```

But when I try the same require call in a `.js.erb`, I got 'undefined' logged.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use requirejs with *.js.erb files. Just because requirejs get files out of [sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-rack-based-asset-packaging).
But instead, you can use [named modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) in *.html.erb views, for instance:

```
<script>
  define('mymodule', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
      user: <%= @user.to_json.html_safe %>
    };
  });
</script>
```